# Magento 2.2.6 to 2.3.2 upgrade issue

Tags: mysql, magento, upgrade, magento-2.3

I have recently upgraded my EE magento 2.2.6 to 2.3.2. The category pages are are showing error on front-end:

> Exception #0 (DomainException): Undefined factory mysql

Also some of my cms pages showing error (possibly due to newly added functionality of Pagebuilder (turning it off doesn't resolve the issue) by Magento):

> Argument 2 passed to Magento\PageBuilder\Plugin\Filter\TemplatePlugin::afterFilter() must be of the type string, null given, called in /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 146

Anyone??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: For part 1: It was some configuration issue, so I downloaded the core_config_data table and replaced it with my staging site one

For part 2: I was using VladmirPopov webforms extension, it was causing the issue in cms pages, so downloaded the latest version of webforms extension and replaced it.